# Ruby And tweenmax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree, gsap

I've tried adding Tweenmax and other JavaScript libraries to my Ruby/Spree app.

But I've not been able to make it work.

I've added separate files to assets/javascripts/store

add included them in the all.js file

Yet it seems that the app doesn't run Tweenmax.

Can someone explain to me how to add Tweenmax to Ruby on Rails & Spree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try greensock-rails gem?

https://github.com/robertpataki/greensock-rails